# All inserts go to same node in Cassandra despite Murmur3 partitioner

Tags: cassandra

I am storing the following column family in Cassandra

```
Mac Address // PKEY
TimeStamp // PKEY
LocationID
ownerName
Signal Strength
```

The primary key is (Mac Address, TimeStamp).

The size of each row is 100 bytes approximately. I have a Cassandra cluster of 4 nodes, each with  1 GB / 512 MB RAM, and 25 GB disk. I inserted 20 million rows of above column family (which translates to 2 GB). Each row inserted has a different MacAddress, so there are no two rows with same MAC Address. From what I understand, Partition will happen on MacAddress, and since there are no same MACs, the 20 million rows should be evenly (well, almost) distributed. I was surprised to find that 99.7% of the data was residing on only one of the nodes. The other three nodes had very little number of rows. My replication factor was set to 1 (since I'm using this setup only for PoC).

Is there any case when such a thing could happen? I could not find any thing on web close to this issue, any help would be appreciated.

---

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
==========
Replicas: 1

Address         Rack        Status State   Load            Owns                Token                                       
                                                                               9158199868423703627                         
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367184151655397632                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367194907514299830                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367205663373202028                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367216419232104226                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367227175091006423                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367237930949908621                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367248686808810819                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367259442667713017                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367270198526615214                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367280954385517412                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367291710244419610                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367302466103321808                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367313221962224005                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367323977821126203                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367334733680028401                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367345489538930599                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367356245397832796                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367367001256734994                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367377757115637192                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               367388512974539390                          
.....
.....
.....
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368646948466096527                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368657704324998725                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368668460183900923                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368679216042803121                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368689971901705318                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368700727760607516                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368711483619509714                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368722239478411912                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368732995337314109                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368743751196216307                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368754507055118505                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368765262914020703                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368776018772922900                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368786774631825098                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368797530490727296                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368808286349629494                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368819042208531691                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368829798067433889                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368840553926336087                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368851309785238285                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368862065644140482                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368872821503042680                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368883577361944878                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368894333220847076                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368905089079749273                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368915844938651471                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368926600797553669                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368937356656455867                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368948112515358064                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368958868374260262                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368969624233162460                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368980380092064658                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               368991135950966855                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369001891809869053                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369012647668771251                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369023403527673449                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369034159386575646                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369044915245477844                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369055671104380042                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369066426963282240                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369077182822184437                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369087938681086635                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369098694539988833                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369109450398891031                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369120206257793228                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369130962116695426                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369141717975597624                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369152473834499822                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369163229693402019                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369173985552304217                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369184741411206415                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369195497270108613                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369206253129010810                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369217008987913008                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369227764846815206                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369238520705717404                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369249276564619601                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369260032423521799                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369270788282423997                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369281544141326195                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369292300000228392                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369303055859130590                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369313811718032788                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369324567576934986                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369335323435837183                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369346079294739381                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369356835153641579                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369367591012543777                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369378346871445974                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369389102730348172                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369399858589250370                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369410614448152568                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369421370307054765                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369432126165956963                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369442882024859161                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369453637883761359                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369464393742663556                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369475149601565754                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369485905460467952                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369496661319370150                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369507417178272347                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369518173037174545                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369528928896076743                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369539684754978941                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369550440613881138                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369561196472783336                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369571952331685534                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369582708190587732                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369593464049489929                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369604219908392127                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369614975767294325                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369625731626196523                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369636487485098720                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369647243344000918                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369657999202903116                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369668755061805314                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369679510920707511                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369690266779609709                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369701022638511907                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369711778497414105                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369722534356316302                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369733290215218500                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369744046074120698                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369754801933022896                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369765557791925093                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369776313650827291                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369787069509729489                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369797825368631687                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369808581227533884                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369819337086436082                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369830092945338280                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369840848804240478                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369851604663142675                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369862360522044873                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369873116380947071                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369883872239849269                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369894628098751467                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369905383957653665                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369916139816555863                          
192.168.121.176 rack1       Up     Normal  758.61 KB       0.03%               369926895675458061                          
192.168.121.129 rack1       Up     Normal  9.5 MB          0.18%               3898129039052635843                         
192.168.121.129 rack1       Up     Normal  9.5 MB          0.18%               3898262574450307387                         
192.168.121.129 rack1       Up     Normal  9.5 MB          0.18%               -4748915780896388021                        
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              -4676858186858460085                        
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              -4604800592820532149                        
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              -4532742998782604213
....
....
....
....
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              3970053097692892235                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4042110691730820171                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4114168285768748107                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4186225879806676043                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4258283473844603979                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4330341067882531915                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4402398661920459851                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4474456255958387787                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4546513849996315723                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4618571444034243659                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4690629038072171595                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4762686632110099531                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4834744226148027467                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4906801820185955403                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              4978859414223883339                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5050917008261811275                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5122974602299739211                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5195032196337667147                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5267089790375595083                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5339147384413523019                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5411204978451450955                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5483262572489378891                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5555320166527306827                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5627377760565234763                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5699435354603162699                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5771492948641090635                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5843550542679018571                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5915608136716946507                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              5987665730754874443                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6059723324792802379                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6131780918830730315                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6203838512868658251                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6275896106906586187                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6347953700944514123                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6420011294982442059                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6492068889020369995                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6564126483058297931                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6636184077096225867                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6708241671134153803                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6780299265172081739                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6852356859210009675                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6924414453247937611                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              6996472047285865547                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7068529641323793483                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7140587235361721419                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7212644829399649355                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7284702423437577291                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7356760017475505227                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7428817611513433163                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7500875205551361099                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7572932799589289035                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7644990393627216971                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7717047987665144907                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7789105581703072843                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7861163175741000779                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              7933220769778928715                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8005278363816856651                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8077335957854784587                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8149393551892712523                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8221451145930640459                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8293508739968568395                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8365566334006496331                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8437623928044424267                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8509681522082352203                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8581739116120280139                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8653796710158208075                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8725854304196136011                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8797911898234063947                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8869969492271991883                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              8942027086309919819                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              9014084680347847755                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              9086142274385775691                         
192.168.121.192 rack1       Up     Normal  5.86 GB         99.72%              9158199868423703627
```

Comment: So, were you able to figure out what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

How did you "see" that 99% of the data was in one node? The reason I ask is because I had a similar problem a few days ago, but I'm not sure if my scenario is the same as yours. I had installed 1.2 Datastax community edition when it was first coming out. I saw that 99.7% of my data was on one node. I decided to use their latest AMI for 1.2, ran the data insertion test again, and then did a nodetool -h localhost ring. I guess the nodetool script was updated because I saw an even distribution and it didn't list all the 512 nodes. It instead listed 2 nodes.

Comment: I am using nodetool status

Comment: So, did you fins out what was the problem?